# Not able to show grouped data correctly in WPF DataGrid

Tags: c#, wpf, datagrid, listcollectionview

I am trying to display my  EF query result (which has a group by clause) and display itinto a DataGrid. I am trying to copy the example here

http://wpftutorial.net/DataGrid.html

So here is my XAML code

```
<DataGrid ItemsSource="{Binding QueryResult}">
    <DataGrid.GroupStyle>
        <GroupStyle>
            <GroupStyle.HeaderTemplate>
                <DataTemplate>
                    <StackPanel>
                        <TextBlock Text="{Binding Path=Name}" />
                    </StackPanel>
                </DataTemplate>
            </GroupStyle.HeaderTemplate>
            <GroupStyle.ContainerStyle>
                <Style TargetType="{x:Type GroupItem}">
                    <Setter Property="Template">
                        <Setter.Value>
                            <ControlTemplate TargetType="{x:Type GroupItem}">
                                <Expander>
                                    <Expander.Header>
                                        <StackPanel Orientation="Horizontal">
                                          <TextBlock Text="{Binding Path=Name}" />
                                          <TextBlock Text="{Binding Path=ItemCount}"/>
                                          <TextBlock Text="Items"/>
                                        </StackPanel>
                                    </Expander.Header>
                                    <ItemsPresenter />
                                </Expander>
                            </ControlTemplate>
                        </Setter.Value>
                    </Setter>
                </Style>
            </GroupStyle.ContainerStyle>
        </GroupStyle>
    </DataGrid.GroupStyle>
</DataGrid>
```

Here is my ViewModel

```
internal void GenerateReport()
{
    Data = Project.GetReport(); **// this is List<IGrouping<string, MyType>>**
    //QueryResult is a ListCollectionView property
    QueryResult= new ListCollectionView(Data);
    QueryResult.GroupDescriptions.Add(new PropertyGroupDescription("train"));
}
```

This is what my result of query looks like

[image: Here is the result of the above code]
    **I do get the key correctly but if you look at my code, I have a collection against the key item. THat is not displaying here. How do I get that to display against each train?**

**EDIT**

I think I have more details on this. Here is how my QueryResult collection looks like

[image]

[image]

Basically my QueryResult has 10 items where each item has a Name, Items and ItemsCounts. 
Each Items itself has 1 item inside which has a key and Group. This group basically contains the items that I want to display in my DataGrid as grouped against parent 10 records that are appearing.

Comment: I think the problem is that you already have grouped list `List<IGrouping<string, MyType>>` you would normally use grouping in `DataGrid` if your list would be flat like `List<MyType>`

Comment: Oh great. It worked. Now only problem is when I click the expander it takes a while to expand depending on no. of items in that category. I have around 50/100 items in each category and it is taking about 15-20 seconds to expand the list.. Any way to improve?